# Restrict monitor access to certain apps

Tags: x11, display, multi-monitor, monitors

I have two monitors setup on my machine. I would like to prevent some apps from accessing one of the two monitors while still granting permission to other apps.

I would like to restrict an application only to HDMI-1-1 (check `xrandr` output below) and prevent it from reading eDP-1-1. Is it possible to do so?

`xrandr` output:

```
een 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Distro: Pop OS 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under X.org **only** session it's not possible, if you run two X.org servers (e.g. by default and then `:1`) programs running at them won't be able to sniff on another X.org server (not directly of course, an evil app may relunch itself with a different DISPLAY variable).

So your best bet will be to have two different user accounts using two different X.org sessions.

I've never used Wayland - it has a much stricter policy but I don't know how to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

You may, however, be able to write something using [devilspie](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/DevilsPie) or [devilspie2](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) to move the window to the HDMI-1-1 monitor if it has opened on eDP-1-1.

devilspie and devilspie2 run in the background, constantly monitoring window-related events, and can take actions using their own scripting language.

`devilspie` is pretty much abandonware and uses its own lisp-like language.
`devilspie2` uses [lua](https://www.lua.org/) as the scripting language.

Alternatively, you could write a shell script using [xdo](https://github.com/baskerville/xdo), [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/), and/or [wmctrl](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/) to do the same.  You could run such a script regularly from cron, or it could run the main body of code in an endless loop (a small sleep between each iteration is highly recommended).